# Find default value of field after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, wordpress

I'm looking for a way, with jQuery, to get the default value of an input field (in an HTML field).

Seems simple enough. Just calling `$("#id-of-field").attr('value')` should return the value I'm wanting right?

Thing is, if the value is `Foo`, when I load the page, it returns `Foo`. No problem there. But if I write `Bar` in the field, then reload (not submit) the page, `$("#id-of-field").attr('value')` will return me `Bar`, even if in the source code, the value attribute of the field is still `Foo`.

That makes validation of my form sticky, because when I get my default values to ignore them if the field has not been filled, I could get a real value in the mix of "Values to be ignored".

FYI, I can't put in the values manually, since the form is dynamic, and cannot query directly the database because it's a Wordpress Website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Input fields have the `defaultValue` DOM property that does exactly what you need.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623535/attrdefaultvalue-is-returning-undefined-using-jquery-1-6-3), the jQuery (> 1.6.3) way to access it is

```
$('#element').prop('defaultValue')
```

Alternatively, in pure JavaScript, e.g. -

```
document.getElementById("element").defaultValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('inputSelector').prop('defaultValue');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try -

```
$("#id-of-field")[0].defaultValue
```

That should get the DOM `defaultValue` property which should give you the original value of the textbox

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textbox#p-defaultValue