# jQuery focus() and empty field

Tags: javascript, jquery, onfocus

I want to empty a login field when it is selected. I'm working with a JS/jQuery-Book and copied the example exactly like this into my document but it doesnt want to work...

Field:

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="Username" name="username" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#username").focus(function(){
    var field = $(this);
    if(field.val() == field.attr("defaultValue")){
    field.val(""); // also tried field.val() = "";
    }
});
});
```

I already put an alert() after each line and I figured out that it doesnt go into the if-statement.

Comment: "Text fields have an attribute called defaultValue, which represents the text inside the field when the page first loads" - JavaScript & jQuery - The missing manual, 2012

Comment: Here's [a link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp) to "defaultValue" documentation.

Comment: Yeah, exactly that is what jQuery uses, but why does it not work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [attr('defaultValue') is returning undefined using jQuery 1.6.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623535/attrdefaultvalue-is-returning-undefined-using-jquery-1-6-3)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
$("#username").focus(function(){
var field = $(this);
var username=field.attr("value");
if(field.val() == username){
    field.val(""); 
}
});
```

It is tested and work properly with your attr also....

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery method `prop` to get the DOM attribute instead of `attr`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#username").focus(function(){
        var field = $(this);
        if(field.val() == field.prop("defaultValue")){   // or: field.val() == field[0].defaultValue
            field.val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "Text fields have an attribute called defaultValue, which represents the text inside the field when the page first loads" - JavaScript & jQuery - The missing manual, 2012

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#username").focus(function(){
    $(this).val("");
});
```

As simple as it can get.

Comment: That works fine. But if you start tiping and then go to the next field and then go to the first field, everything you already typed will be erased...

Comment: why don't you use a placeholder instead ? like
<input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username"  name="username" />

Answer (score 0):

Use .prop() (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WWG3S/)):

```
$("#username").focus(function(){
    var field = $(this);

    if(field.val() == field.prop("defaultValue")) {
        field.val("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

`<input type="text" id="username" value="Username" name="username" defaultValue="" />`

And try it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#username").focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() === $(this).attr("defaultValue")){
            $(this).val("");
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var user = $("#username").val();
$("#username").focus(function()
{
if($(this).val()==user)
$(this).val("");
});
});
```

This works fine for me.